# proccess.binding("net") - No such module

Tags: http, node.js, binding, process

When using multi-node with node v0.5.10, I receive the following error:

Error code : http://pastebin.com/SQi6v2Ap

Which is referring to netBinding = process.binding("net");

I have tried to use the following solution : (http)nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html, as the people in this thread advised me to: https://github.com/kriszyp/multi-node/issues/14

I have researched for tutorials to install the simplecluster, but to no avail. I really appreciated if someone could provide a extremely lay-man guide as I am very new unfortunately, and it would mean so much to me if someone could give me a dummy-prove step by step guide to 'install' this module ( I have never installed any module before, only recently stumbled into the world of node js and still exploring ) Help is appreciated and thanks so much